HTML link for embedded video
I have the following code in an HTML web page and the first tag does not work. A video window just shows up and is blank. The second tag which is an anchor to exactly the same file does work. It shows a hyperlink and if the link is clicked then the video appears.
    <video controls>
        <source src="./mydir/file-xyz.MP4" type="video /mpeg">
        Your browser does not support the video element.
    </video >
    <a href="./mydir/file-xyz.MP4" type="video /mpeg">File XYZ</a>

What am I doing wrong in the first tag (video controls)?

Notice the space (typo?) you have here type="video /mpeg". That likely breaks the type you intended. Besides that I think its just wrong ("mpeg"). Try type="video/mp4" and without the space.
